# Increment inital value in foreach with php

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to find a way to implement a counter initial variable in foreach loop. So what I need is something like this:

```
<?php

$maxAttributeSections = 15;
$i = 1;

?>

<table class="border">
<?php foreach ($this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i} as $label => $value): ?>
    <tr class="attribute-pane">
        <td class="attribute-pane-title" width="26%"><?= $label; ?></td>
        <td class="attribute-pane-title border" width="74%"> <?= $value["text"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I need to loop that attributeSectionAttribute variable 15 times. So to be attributeSectionAttribute1, attributeSectionAttribute2, attributeSectionAttribute3 ... 15.

I am kind of stuck so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. I have 15 attribute sections and need to display them all. I know I can do it copy paste 15 times, but I want to practice better coding :)

Comment: Why do you have 15 variables anyway, wouldn't it be easier to have an array of the values instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can not increment inside `foreach()` condition,*** so use `for()` loop:-

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) : ?> 
<table class="border"> 
    <?php foreach ($this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i} as $label => $value): ?> 
        <tr class="attribute-pane">
            <td class="attribute-pane-title" width="26%"><?= $label; ?></td> 
            <td class="attribute-pane-title border" width="74%"><?= $value["text"]; ?> </td> 
        </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table> 
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: @user2450639 Based on your comment under TarangP's answer, it seems you should be awarding the green tick to AlivetoDie.  Please reward this volunteer for their adequate support.  Also, if you tell NigelRen the correct syntax to access the `$label` value, then his way _may be_ better practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach ($this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i} as $label => $value):

if($i == $maxAttributeSections )
break; //this will break the loop once it reaches 15

?>
    <tr class="attribute-pane">
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

*JUST ADD SIMPLE CONDITION*

```
<table class="border">
<?php 
    $arr = $this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i};
    foreach ($arr as $label => $value): 
?>
    <tr class="attribute-pane">
        <td class="attribute-pane-title" width="26%"><?= $label; ?></td>
        <td class="attribute-pane-title border" width="74%"> <?= $value["text"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $i++; 
    //JUST ADD SIMPLE CONDITION
    if($i > $maxAttributeSections){
        break;
    }
    endforeach; 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: And What `$this->{'attributeSectionAttribute'` This will Return ?

Comment: If I do this: <?php dump($this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i}); ?> inside foreach It will show the correct result, but I quess increment is not working for that initial value, so it is always 1. I need to find some other way to increment initial value, working on it :)

Comment: Try by my Updated Answer. or still not work try to echo `$arr` And show us what it will returns.

Comment: The $arr is returning the single array, but it still does not get incremented :(.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `for()` loop instead...

```
<table class="border">
<?php 
for ( $i = 1; $i<= 15 $i++ ):
    $label = 'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i;    // Correct this
    $value = $this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i};
?>
    <tr class="attribute-pane">
        <td class="attribute-pane-title" width="26%"><?= $label; ?></td>
        <td class="attribute-pane-title border" width="74%"> <?= $value["text"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

I'm not sure what `$label` is supposed to display, so I've left it as the field name, it may be that you have to change this to suit what your after.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that the initial value did not increment at all. $this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i} was always $this->attributeSectionAttribute1 because that variable was not in the foreach body. I solved this problem by adding for loop and put the foreach inside of it:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) : ?>
<table class="border">
    <?php foreach ($this->{'attributeSectionAttribute' . $i} as $label => $value): ?>
        <tr class="attribute-pane">
            <td class="attribute-pane-title" width="26%"><?= $label; ?></td>
            <td class="attribute-pane-title border" width="74%"><?= $value["text"]; ?> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endfor; ?>
```